# Use SpeechSynthesizer in Dutch

Tags: c#

I want to use tts in c# and my code works fine for English, but now I want to use it in Dutch.

```
private void btnSpeak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

     foreach (var v in synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
     {
         VoiceInfo info = v.VoiceInfo;
         OutputVoiceInfo(info);
     }

     synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
     synthesizer.Volume = 100;  // 0...100
     synthesizer.Rate = 1;     // -10...10

     // Synchronous
     if(textBox1.Text != null)
         synthesizer.SpeakAsync(textBox1.Text);
}

private static void OutputVoiceInfo(VoiceInfo info)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, culture: {1}, gender: {2}, age: {3}.\n", info.Name, info.Culture, info.Gender, info.Age);
     Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}\n", info.Description);
}
```

Is there anything I should install so it is capable of speaking Dutch?

Comment: See the remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586875.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues. Running the following PowerShell resolved it:

```
$sourcePath = 'HKLM:\software\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices\Tokens' #Where the OneCore voices live
$destinationPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens' #For 64-bit apps
$destinationPath2 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\SPEECH\Voices\Tokens' #For 32-bit apps
cd $destinationPath
$listVoices = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath
foreach($voice in $listVoices)
{
$source = $voice.PSPath #Get the path of this voices key
copy -Path $source -Destination $destinationPath -Recurse
copy -Path $source -Destination $destinationPath2 -Recurse
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/hiepxanh/8b6ad80f6d620cd3eaaaa5c1d2c660b2

Running your example uses the Dutch TTS engine *Microsoft Frank*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can speak any language installed in Windows that supports the selected culture. Are you sure you have installed a voice that is capable of speaking dutch (I assume the `nl-NL` culture)? You should find this in the output of the console written by your `OutputVoiceInfo()` method.

Comment: I haven't installed a voice yet, is there a free voice you can suggest?

Comment: @just8laze Dutch versions of Windows have a dutch voice installed by default. For the free / pre-installed versions; this one is the best. However there are some free voices available that you can use during development.